# jQuery: having trouble specifying minDate and maxDate for a datePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to enforce choosing only dates between (today minus a week, today plus a week) but instead getting a datePicker with past dates disabled and unrestricted future dates.

Any idea? (I'm new to jQuery, 2nd day of playing with it...) thanks!

I isolated the code to clearly repro it:

```
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                                  
    <title>jquery sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datePicker.js"></script>
    <link href="datePicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(function () {
            $('.date-pick').datePicker({ minDate: '-7D', maxDate: '+7D' }).val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>                                                                  
    <a href="">Link</a>
    <input name="date1" id="date1" class="date-pick" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are different for your current plugin, [`startDate` and `endDate`](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/documentation.html) and they must be strings, like this:

```
$(function () {
  $('.date-pick').datePicker({ 
     startDate : new Date().addDays(-7).asString(), 
     endDate: new Date().addDays(7).asString()
  }).val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/U2y3u/).  The documentation you seemed to have pulled from is for a *different* plugin, the jQuery UI Datepicker [found here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: @Nick, that's the case. I'm cleaning this up... Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like the `startDate` and `endDate` take that format. Check out your demo again - the datepicker's looking at 1900, not 2010.

Comment: @Bears: yes, noticed that. Also noticed that even after choosing a date it doesn't show up in the text control. But anyway, I appreciate to be pointed out about my confussion of using different controls, I'll figure these out later. Thanks both!

Comment: @Ariel - @Bears make a good catch, check out the updated version, it points to the correct dates.

Comment: What browser/framework gives you `addDays()`? It's definitely not standard.

Comment: @Bears - It's in the `date.js` he's including, a prerequisite for `.datePicker()`, you can view it here: http://github.com/vitch/jquery-methods/raw/master/date.js

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're mixing up the same two datepickers that I did, as [@Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13249/nick-craver) pointed out. The datepicker plugin you're using doesn't take `minDate` and `maxDate` options: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/documentation.html

But the jQuery UI datepicker does. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-minDate

Which one did you mean to use? If it's the plugin (not the jQuery UI one), then use the `startDate` and `endDate` options (looks like they only accept absolute-date strings [kind of crappy, IMO]):

```
$(function() {
    var MS_PER_WEEK = 604800000;
        now = new Date().getTime(),
        start = new Date(now - MS_PER_WEEK),
        end = new Date(now + MS_PER_WEEK),
        startStr = start.getDate() + '/' + (start.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + start.getFullYear(),
        endStr = end.getDate() + '/' + (end.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + end.getFullYear()

    $('.date-pick').datePicker({
        startDate: startStr
        endDate: endStr
    }).val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
});
```

<strike>For the jQuery UI datepicker, try a lowercase `d` to indicate days:</strike>

```
$(function() {
    $('.date-pick').datepicker({
        minDate: '-7d',
        maxDate: '+7d'
    }).val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: I think you're writing an answer for the jQuery UI datepicker...this is a different plugin :)

Comment: @Nick: Blargh. You're right. I was wondering why this wasn't working in jsfiddle...

Comment: The plugin in question is: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/

Comment: @Nick @Bears: I'm trying above and still not working. I'm confused by your comment Nick - am I not using jQuery UI datepicker? I meant so, I'm RTFM, http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker, thanks!

Comment: @danielgwood: Oh, I see now. I may be pointing out to a different date picker... let me clean this up. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use startDate and endDate instead:

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker({ startDate: '-2D', endDate: '+2D' }).val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
```

That is, assuming you are using the plugin described here: [kevinluck.com](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/). This works for me on my local test. I assume you are using this plugin due to the similarity to the examples on Kevin's site.